# Date in variable - mysql

Tags: mysql, variables, date, casting

i would need to help how can i save into my variable `@today` from `CURRENT_DATE()` value on `VARCHAR` type as you can see in first SET row and in the second row in my variable `@yesterday` i would like to save the value in DATE type.

```
SET @today=CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS VARCHAR(50)),
@yesterday=CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS DATE)

SELECT @today, @yesterday
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: why store as var-char? If you select a date-type field out from mysql, it'll be a string `yyyy-mm-dd` in pretty much all clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That may help:

```
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS CHAR(50)) INTO @today;
SELECT CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS DATE) INTO @yesterday;

SELECT @today, @yesterday
```

EDIT:
Your version also works, but You can't cast into VARCHAR()

```
SET @today=CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS CHAR(50)) , 
@yesterday=CAST(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -1 DAY) AS DATE) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment it is helpful, but the result of @yesterday is (BLOB). Is it correct?

Comment: How can I use a variable within the Where clause?

Comment: @Reya276 first you need to SET it (as @today) , and then WHERE YOUR_DATE=@TODAY